# (crypto.js) TypeError: Data must be string or buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently using crypto.js module to hash things. It was working for a while then I started getting this error:

[image]

Here is the foundation of my server:

```
process.stdout.write('\033c'); // Clear the console on startup

var
    express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    http = require("http").Server(app),
    io = require("socket.io")(http),
    path = require("path"),
    colorworks = require("colorworks").create(),

    fs = require("fs"),

    crypto = require("crypto");

    function md5(msg){
        return crypto.createHash("md5").update(msg).digest("base64");
    }
    function sha256(msg) {
        return crypto.createHash("sha256").update(msg).digest("base64");
    }

        http.listen(443, function(){
        // Create the http server so it can be accessed via 127.0.0.1:443 in a web browser.

            console.log("NJ project webserver is running on port 443.");
            // Notify the console that the server is up and running

        });

        app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

        app.get("/", function(request, response){
            response.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
        });
```

I am aware that these functions are creating the problem:

```
    function md5(msg){
        return crypto.createHash("md5").update(msg).digest("base64");
    }
    function sha256(msg) {
        return crypto.createHash("sha256").update(msg).digest("base64");
    }
```

The problem being, if these functions don't work (which they don't anymore), roughly 200 lines of code will go to waste.

Comment: Where do you use this functions?

Comment: @RonDadon I call the functions in various areas of my server (usually when sockets are received though). Here is an example: `var usernameEncryption = sha256(md5(salt));`

Comment: Try to run it in debug and place a break point in the function to check the data that is passed via the `msg` argument, because in at least one call you are not passing a string (or a buffer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is triggered by attempting to hash a variable that does not exist:

```
function md5(msg){
    return crypto.createHash("md5").update(msg).digest("base64");
}
function sha256(msg) {
    return crypto.createHash("sha256").update(msg).digest("base64");
}
md5(non_existent); // This variable does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2):

What kind of data are you trying to hash ? Where does it come from ?
I would check the value of msg first then I would try :

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update(msg.toString()).digest('hex');
```

You could also use these packages instead:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256

Comment: I am trying to hash text

Comment: can you check what value msg has before getting hashed ? like console.log(msg)